# Ubuntu 18.04; Won't Boot After Shutdown

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia

Seeing some odd behavior after shutting down my PC running Ubuntu 18.04. I did a hard push on the power button after the computer crashed while trying to kill an intense process that became a Zombie (I think this is unrelated).

After turning my computer on again I got to the splash page with 5 dots.

[image]

I restarted and found I am now automatically given the grub menu. If I do *not* select Advanced Options, and just allow for a normal boot, I am not met with a four dot splash screen.

[image]

If I choose Ctrl+C, I get an emergency mode shell (same as root)?  But I am unsure of where to go from here.

[image]

I expect the problem is with my nvidia-driver.  While trying to install a large software package (AlphaFold) I believe I may have changed my nvidia and CUDA installation outside of a virtual environment.

I have a bootable Ubuntu 21.04 USB in the machine which I can also boot from.

If I got to recovery mode the system stops at 100% at Checking in Progress on 1 disk

[image]

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait?  Something stopped your disk from properly loading up so a file system integrity check is being run.  It can take time to run.  Let it complete, no matter how long it takes.  OTHERWISE, your system might not function properly.

Comment: Got it. I had stopped it after ~ 1 hour. Ill let it run the rest of the day.